# Visual Studio WiX and patches

Tags: visual-studio, wix, votive

I tried to build a WiX patch with Visual Studio. Easy enough. I build with Visual Studio, and it builds. But, when I try to run the resulting [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer), I am told

> This installation package could not
>   be opened.  Contact the application
>   vendor to verify tat this is a valid
>   Windows Installer package.

Ideally, I would be creating a much smaller msp path file, but, for sake of simplicity, I am OK with an MSI file. How do I do this with Visual Studio, or, do I need to drop down to the command line and use candle.exe, light.exe, torch.exe & pyro.exe?

The WiX code looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Patch
          AllowRemoval="yes"
          Classification="Update"
          Comments="Some Patch for v 1.0.0"
          Description="Updates Some Software to v 1.0.1"
          DisplayName="Some software Patch 03/07/2011"
          Manufacturer="MyMfg"
          TargetProductName="SomeProduct">

        <Media Id="1000" Cabinet="Inspect.cab">
            <PatchBaseline Id="SomeBaseLine" />
        </Media>
        <PatchFamily
              Id="SomeFamily"
              Version="1.0.1.0"
              ProductCode="<GUID>"
              Supersede="yes">

            <ComponentRef Id="ComponentsToPatch" />
        </PatchFamily>
    </Patch>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Votive](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/) doesn't have a patch project type. The WiX MSBuild targets include a [Torch](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/alltools.html) task but not a [Pyro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Pyro) task, so you can do everything with MSBuild but need to use [Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) to run Pyro. There's an open feature request to support patching, both within Visual Studio and the MSBuild targets.